# Working with Rc and Object Safety

Tags: rust

I'm writing a library that includes several geometric shapes. Each shape is either fully refined (meaning the rendering system can display it), or is made up of subshapes. Each shape has two methods: a method that checks if it is fully refined, and a method that gets a list of its subshapes, if any. Refinement is then done on each of those subshapes until I have a list of shapes, each of which is fully refined. Because I'm reading these shapes in from a file, I was hoping to use `Rc`s to simplify memory management.

A few shapes need to have references to their "parent" shapes. I was hoping to use `Rc`s for these references as well. Because of this, the parent's refine method needs to take an `Rc`, since it needs to clone that `Rc` and give the clone to its children.

All in all, here's what I would like to have:

```
trait Shape {
  fn is_fully_refined(&self) -> bool { true }
  fn refine(shape: &Rc<Self>) -> Vec<Rc<Shape>> { Vec::new() }
}

struct Parent { ... }

impl Shape for Parent {
  fn is_fully_refined(&self) -> bool { false }

  fn refine(shape: &Rc<Parent>) -> Vec<Rc<Shape>> {
    let child = Child { parent: shape.clone };
    vec![child]
  }
}

struct Child { parent: Rc<Parent> }

impl Shape for Child { }
```

The problem is that `Shape` is not object safe because `refine` uses `Self`. Is there a way to structure this so that I can both have `Rc<Shape>` and a refine method that "knows" about the reference count, so it can be cloned?

I would also like to be able to call `refine` on an `Rc<Shape>`, in order to recursively refine my shapes until I have a list of fully-refined shapes.

I have seen extension traits used before, but I don't think that will work in this case. I would need to have a single `impl` for the hypothetical `ShapeExt`, or whatever, and each shape refines differently.

I've also seen `where` clauses used to guard the methods that make a trait object safe, but then I couldn't call `refine` on an `Rc<Shape>` (I think).

Is this possible in Rust, or do I need to restructure my code entirely?

Comment: FYI, Rust standard formatting is 4-space indents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The help for error E0038](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0038) suggests that you can add `where Self: Sized` to a non-object-safe method to avoid the error. And indeed, it works:

```
trait Shape {
    fn is_fully_refined(&self) -> bool { true }
    fn refine(shape: &Rc<Self>) -> Vec<Rc<Shape>> where Self: Sized { Vec::new() }
}
```

However, since the `refine` function uses `&Rc<Self>`, you can't use the method syntax (`x.refine()`) to invoke it. Instead, you need to write `Shape::refine(&x)`. If you want to be able to write the former, you'll need to move the `refine` function to another trait and implement that trait for each `Rc<T>` where `T` implements `Shape`. For example:

```
trait RefinableShape {
    fn refine(&self) -> Vec<Rc<Shape>> { Vec::new() }
}

impl RefinableShape for Rc<Parent> {
    fn refine(&self) -> Vec<Rc<Shape>> {
        let child = Child { parent: self.clone() };
        vec![Rc::new(child)]
    }
}

impl RefinableShape for Rc<Child> { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've marked `refine` with `where Self: Sized`, but when I try to call `Shape::refine(&shape)` on object of type `Rc<Shape>`, I get an error saying that "the trait core::marker::Sized is not implemented for the type Shape". Does the solution with the where clause only work for non-trait-objects?

Also, if I add a constraint on Shape like this: `trait Shape: Sized { ... }`, I'm told that "the trait Shape is not implemented for the type Shape", which, I'll admit, I find a little confusing.

Comment: `Shape` designates two different things: a trait and a type. Rust tries to make the type `Shape` implement the trait `Shape` when possible, but adding a `Sized` constraint prevents that, since the type `Shape` is unsized (not all types implementing `Shape` have the same size). Make sure to read the book's chapter on [Trait Objects](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/trait-objects.html) to understand all the details.

Comment: So, the answer is "no, this is not possible in Rust"?

Comment: `Child` wants to store an `Rc<Parent>`, but what you have is an `Rc<Shape>`. I don't think you can go from an `Rc<Shape>` to an `Rc<Parent>`. Perhaps you could replace `Rc<Shape>` with `Box<RefinableShape>` everywhere?